# Dynamically updating a wrapper class based on records of different objects

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

I've written the following WrapperClass, consisting different object records as members. How can I dynamically update this wrapper class object.

Example : If a contact record is created, it should be pushed to the wrapper class newContact member, lly for Account and other custom objects.

```
    public class ParentClass{
        public class WrapperClass{

            public map<String,String> refMap {get;set;}
            public Contact newContact {get;set;}
            public Account newAccount {get;set;}
            public CustomObj1__c newCustomObj1Rec {get;set;}
            public CustomObj2__c newCustomObj2Rec {get;set;}    

            public WrapperClass(Map<String,String> refM,Contact c,Account a,CustomObj1__c c1,CustomObject2__c c2) {
                this.refMap =refM;
                this.newContact=c;
                this.newAccount=a;
                this.newCustomObj1Rec=c1;
                this.newCustomObj2Rec=c2; 
            }

        }
   }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your question is not clear, what is the purpose of creating wrapper class?

Comment: Consider multiple forms, each related to single object. I want to save data of each of these forms into a wrapper class. So that at the end of final form, I would get all the data in single wrapper class object.

Comment: you can create an instance of the wrapper class and pass values as parameters. Now what's the specific issues you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the below sample code for your query.

```
public class ParentClass{
public class WrapperClass{
    public map<String,String> refMap {get;set;}
    public sObject sObjectRec {get;set;} // sobject - Generic Object
    public WrapperClass(Map<String,String> refM, sObject sObjectRecord) {
        refMap = refM;
        sObjectRec = sObjectRecord; // sobject - Generic Object
    }
}
```

}

// Before instantiating the wrapper, convert your specific object record to sobject record. Example:

```
sobject sobjectRecord = (sobject)contactRecord;
```

// Use the below code in your business logic to get OBJECT NAME as string from the record

```
String objName = sObjectRec.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
```